# Button to count the enqueued item and dequeued item in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have A button that show the Dequeued item in my view.

Here is my controller for dequeuing item:

```
    public ActionResult BtnNext()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        var first = MyQueue.todayQueue.Dequeue();
        TempData["QueueItem"] = first;
        return PartialView("_queuenumber");
    }
```

Then here is my view for that, it renders the dequeued item.

```
@{
    var item = (Rosh.QueueMe.Web.Models.MyQueue)TempData["QueueItem"];
}

<div id="current">
    <p>@item.QueueNumber</p>
</div>
```

I want to show in the view how many items there is in the Queue, and when I hit the `BtnNext()` again it will hopefully update the Remaining number in the Queue.

### -------------------------------------------------------

I have here another button of `BtnFinish()`

**Expected behavior:**
When I hit this button I just want my View to be cleared but not Dequeue the next item in line. and Count how many item's I already finished.

So in my view there will be a part for item I finished, and A part for Items remaining in the Queue.

```
    public PartialViewResult BtnFinish()
    {

         return View();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything referencing the `Count` property of a queue. That's what would tell you how many are left. Instead of using the item returned from the queue as a view model, you would need a view model with two properties: One property is the item returned from the queue, and the other is that count. Now both things that you want to display are in your view model, and you can render them in your view however you want.

Comment: @Hien Nguyen hi